# How to use Django join

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views

Hi I am making a backend server in Django for storing user data from an app.
Below are my models.

```
class Subscriber(models.Model):
    subId = models.IntegerField(max_length=20,unique=True,blank=False)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True)

class SMS(models.Model):
    subscriberId = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=False)
    epochTime =  models.IntegerField(null = False)
    time = models.CharField(max_length= 250 ,blank = False)

class Call(models.Model):
    subscriberId = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=True)
    epochTime =  models.IntegerField(null = False)
    time = models.CharField(max_length= 50 ,blank = False)
    Date = models.CharField(max_length= 50 ,blank = False)
```

I need to write a Django query which I will give subscriberId and Django will return me to use the data for that user from Call and SMS (basically wants to use Join ).
earlier I have applied this in mysql.

```
select * from Server_Text JOIN (Server_Call) ON (Server_SMS.subscriberId_id = 11 and Server_Call.subscriberId_id = 11) ;
```

where Server is my mysql Database.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Is this something you've already looked at?

Comment: yes, but I don't get a perfect solution for this problem. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't think in terms of joins and sql queries when you're using Django; the point is that the model layer abstracts these away. You just want to get the Subscriber, then follow the relationships to get the SMS and Call info:

```
subscriber = Subscriber.objects.get(subId=my_subscriber_id)
print subscriber.sms_set.all()  # all SMSs for that subscriber
print subscriber.call_set.all() # all Calls for that subscriber
```

If you're doing this a lot, you can make it a bit more efficient by using `prefetch_related('sms', 'call')` in the initial query.